# Markov Chain montecarlo integration and infinite while loop

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop, montecarlo, markov-chains

I'm implementing a Markov Chain Montecarlo with metropolis and barkes alphas for numerical integration. I've created a class called `MCMCIntegrator()`. I've loaded it with some attributes, one of then is the pdf of the function (a lambda) we're trying to integrate called `g`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st


class MCMCIntegrator:

    def __init__(self):

        self.g = lambda x: st.gamma.pdf(x, 0, 1, scale=1 / 1.23452676)*np.abs(np.cos(1.123454156))
        self.size = 10000
        self.std = 0.6
        self.real_int = 0.06496359
```

There are other methods in this class, the `size` is the size of the sample that the class must generate, `std` is the standard deviation of the Normal Kernel, which you will see in a few seconds. The `real_int` is the value of the integral from 1 to 2 of the function we're integrating. I've generated it with a R script. Now, to the problem.

```
 def _chain(self, method=None):

        """
            Markov chain heat-up with burn-in

        :param method: Metrpolis or barker alpha
        :return: np.array containing the sample
        """
        old = 0
        sample = np.zeros(int(self.size * 1.5))
        i = 0

        if method:
            def alpha(a, b): return min(1, self.g(b) / self.g(a))

        else:
            def alpha(a, b): return self.g(b) / (self.g(a) + self.g(b))

        while i != len(sample):
            new = st.norm(loc=old, scale=self.std).rvs()
            new = abs(new)
            al = alpha(old, new)
            u = st.uniform.rvs()

            if al > u:
                sample[i] = new
                old = new
                i += 1

        return np.array(sample)
```

Below this method is an `integrate()` method that calculates the proportion of numbers in the [1, 2] interval:

```
    def integrate(self, method=None):
        """
            Integration step

        """

        sample = self._chain(method=method)
        
        # discarding 30% of the sample for the burn-in
        ind = int(len(sample)*0.3)
        sample = sample[ind:]
        setattr(self, "sample", sample)

        sample = [1 if 1 < v < 2 else 0 for v in sample]
        return np.mean(sample)
```

This is the main function:

```
def main():

    print("-- RESULTS --".center(20), end='\n')
    mcmc = MCMCIntegrator()
    print(f"\t{mcmc.integrate()}", end='\n')
    print(f"\t{np.abs(mcmc.integrate() - mcmc.real_int) / mcmc.real_int}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm stuck in an infinity while loop and I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: code cannot be executed as shown.  `new` variable in `_chain` is undefined.  Many other style recommendations beyond that...

Comment: ... turn `g` into a class function...  labeling a lambda kinda defeats purpose of lambda.  you are conditionally defining the function `alpha`, which is bad form.  Just make a function and sent it input to define how to act.  later, you are redefining alpha to be a variable, overwriting the named function....

Comment: I've seen the problems with variables,, i've changed it just like the way my code is right now, still with the same issues. I'll be happy to hear your advices to change the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...  You are hung up in the chain method because the alpha computation is returning NaN, because g() is returning NaN.  Take a look at the print statements I inserted into your code and run it...

tips:

1. Make g() a class function just like `chain`.
2. Test g() on some test values, something is clearly amiss
3. Don't conditionally define a function like `alpha`.  Wayyy confusing and error prone/tough to troubleshoot.  Just pass alpha what it needs and you also can make it a class function `alpha(a, b, method=None)`
4. Take a look at where you are updating i in the `_chain' function....  You realize you are risking a long looping process because you only update i conditionally!
5. You are set up for disaster with your use of `numpy` array.  You may have a bunch of trailing zeros after your actual data because you are over-writing the large zeros list.  You do NOT need `numpy` array here, just use a python empty list and append new values to it, either zero or one...based on whatever.

Add a couple print statements in when you are troubleshooting (or unit test your functions).  Try my adds to your function below...  it is what I used to figure out what was going on

```
def _chain(self, method=None, verbose=True):

    """
        Markov chain heat-up with burn-in

    :param method: Metrpolis or barker alpha
    :return: np.array containing the sample
    """
    old = 0
    sample = np.zeros(int(self.size * 1.5))
    i = 0

    if method:
        def alpha(a, b): return min(1, self.g(b) / self.g(a))

    else:
        def alpha(a, b): 
            if verbose: print(f'g(a): {self.g(a)}, g(b): {self.g(b)}')
            return self.g(b) / (self.g(a) + self.g(b))

    while i != len(sample):
        new = st.norm(loc=old, scale=self.std).rvs()
        new = abs(new)
        al = alpha(old, new)
        u = st.uniform.rvs()
        if verbose: print(f'old: {old:.3f} new: {new:.3f} alpha: {al:.3f} u: {u:.3f}')
        if al > u:
            sample[i] = new
            old = new
            i += 1              # do you really want to conditionally update i?
        sys.exit(-1)            # to breakout of infinite loop...


    return np.array(sample)
```

Comment: You have no idea how much it helped me, im really grateful thank you.

Comment: The world runs on thank you's!  That is good to go by me... good luck!

Comment: Made the changes, the program is way more smooth